# How to add custom shipping charge in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add shipping charge using code in woocommerce. here is my reuirements.

If my shipping country is Australia then shipping charge is different and outside australia is also different.
now, if my shipping country is Australia and

```
1. if order value is < 100, then shipping charge is $100 
2. if order value is > 100, then shipping charge is $0.
```

If my shipping country is outside Australia and

```
 1. if order value is < 500, then shipping charge is $60
 2. if order value is > 500 and < 1000, then shipping charge is $50
 3. if order value is > 1000, then shipping charge is $0
```

So, how can I add custom shipping charge as per my above requirements when user change shipping country from checkout page.
I tried below code but it only works on order value, how can I add shipping country in below code in custom plugin.

```
class WC_Your_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
    public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
    global $woocommerce;
        if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal > 5000) {
            $cost = 30; 
        }else{
            $cost = 3000;
      }
}
$rate = array(
    'id' => $this->id,
    'label' => $this->title,
    'cost' => $cost,
    'calc_tax' => 'per_order'
);

// Register the rate
$this->add_rate( $rate );
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better to make custom plugin for shipping charge where you can use hook.
First extend 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method' class in your custom plugin and make function like this:

```
public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
    session_start();
    global $woocommerce;

    $carttotal = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
    $country = $_POST['s_country']; //$package['destination']['country'];

    if($country == 'AU')
    {
        if($carttotal > 100){
            $cost = 5;
        }else{
            $cost = 10;//10.00;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($carttotal < 500){
            $cost = 60;//60.00;
        }else if($carttotal >= 500 && $carttotal <= 1000){
            $cost = 50;//50.00;
        }else if($carttotal > 1000){
            $cost = 0;
        }
    }

    $rate = array(
        'id' => $this->id,
        'label' => 'Shipping',
        'cost' => $cost,
        'calc_tax' => 'per_order'
    );

    // Register the rate
    $this->add_rate( $rate );
}
```

Comment: hey, its working.. thanks very much for this code. I got my solution from above function

Answer (score -1):

first make a shipping method in admin name as 'myship'

then add below code in your theme functions.php file

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_when_produts_in_cart');

function discount_when_produts_in_cart( ) {

    global $woocommerce;

 $coupon_code = 'myship';

    if( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() > 500 ) {

        $coupon_code = 'myship';

   }

 else

 {

   $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons(sanitize_text_field($coupon_code));

    $woocommerce->clear_messages();

 }
```

Comment: Hi, mahy i know why you add coupon code? and how can I know that which shipping country is selected in above code?

Comment: This does not really answer OP's question.