# Add custom shipping methods in woocommerce using the cart total items

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help completing this code. I have been trying to make a plugin for my woocommerce site to auto add a shipping cost basing on the total items ordered. ie When I try my code below, It returns a value of eleven irregardless of the number of items I order. Ideal siutation is below:

1-5 packs 5,000
6-10 packs 10,000
11-15 packs 15,000
16-20 packs 20,000

Here is my code below.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Your Shipping plugin
Plugin URI: http://woothemes.com/woocommerce
Description: Your shipping method plugin
Version: 1.0.0
Author: WooThemes
Author URI: http://woothemes.com
*/


/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 */

if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    function your_shipping_method_init() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
            class WC_Your_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
                /**
                 * Constructor for your shipping class
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function __construct() {
                    $this->id                 = 'your_shipping_method'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                    $this->method_title       = __( 'Your Shipping Method' );  // Title shown in admin
                    $this->method_description = __( 'Description of your shipping method' ); // Description shown in admin

                    $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                    $this->title              = "My Shipping Method"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

                    $this->init();
                }

                /**
                 * Init your settings
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                function init() {
                    // Load the settings API
                    $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                    $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

                    // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
                }

                /**
                 * calculate_shipping function.
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @param mixed $package
                 * @return void
                 */

                public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
                    session_start();
                    global $woocommerce;

                    $carttotal = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;

                    /*
                        1-5 packs 5,000
                        6-10 packs 10,000
                        11-15 packs 15,000
                        16-20 packs 20,000

                    */
                    if($carttotal < 20){
                        $cost = 0;//Free delivery for above 20 packs
                    }else if($carttotal >= 16 && $carttotal <= 20){
                        $cost = 20000;
                    }else if($carttotal >= 11 && $carttotal <= 15){
                        $cost = 15000;
                    }else if($carttotal >= 6 && $carttotal <= 10){
                        $cost = 10000;
                    }else if($carttotal >= 5 && $carttotal <= 1){
                        $cost = 5000;
                    }else if($carttotal > 1){
                        $cost = 0;
                    }

                    $rate = array(
                        'id' => $this->id,
                        'label' => 'Shipping',
                        'cost' => $cost
                    );

                    // Register the rate
                    $this->add_rate( $rate );

                }
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'your_shipping_method_init' );

    function add_your_shipping_method( $methods ) {
        $methods['your_shipping_method'] = 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_your_shipping_method' );
}
```

I got some help from Credit help: [How to add custom shipping charge in woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666501/how-to-add-custom-shipping-charge-in-woocommerce) but now I need to complete this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your calculate_shipping function has some problems

```
if($carttotal < 20){
     $cost = 0;//Free delivery for above 20 packs
```

should be

```
if($carttotal > 20){
```

and

```
}else if($carttotal >= 5 && $carttotal <= 1){
```

is backwards, it reads "greater than or equal to 5 and less than or equal to 1"

should be

```
}else if($carttotal >= 1 && $carttotal <= 5){
```

also your last else if in that statement is confusing, the rest of the if's should have covered every number between 1 and 20+

```
 }else if($carttotal > 1){
    $cost = 0;
```

You can probably just remove that part.

Comment: Thanks for the quick correction. Much appreciate them however the issue still remains. For whatever number of items I order, it returns value of 11 as shipping

Answer (score 0):

I just unwrapped the functions out of the conditional statement

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
```

Don't forget the final closing brace at the bottom. I killed a few standards i.e not make it a plugin but just made a new file (avoid clutter) for inclusion in my functions.php

so for functions.php I added

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/woo-shipping-methods.php';
```

And /inc/woo-shipping-methods.php file

had this code

```
<?php

function your_shipping_method_init() {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
        class WC_Your_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {

            /*----------------------------------------------------------------
                    Constructor for your shipping class 
            ----------------------------------------------------------------*/
            public function __construct() {
                $this->id                 = 'your_shipping_method'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                $this->method_title       = __( 'Your Shipping Method' );  // Title shown in admin
                $this->method_description = __( 'Description of your shipping method' ); // Description shown in admin

                $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                $this->title              = "My Shipping Method"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

                $this->init();
            }

            /*----------------------------------------------------------------
                Init your settings
            ----------------------------------------------------------------*/
            function init() {
                // Load the settings API
                $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

                // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            }

            /*----------------------------------------------------------------
                calculate_shipping function.
            ----------------------------------------------------------------*/

            public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
                global $woocommerce;

                $carttotal = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;

                /*
                    1-5 packs 5,000
                    6-10 packs 10,000
                    11-15 packs 15,000
                    16-20 packs 20,000

                */
                if($carttotal > 20){
                    $cost = 0;//Free delivery for above 20 packs
                }else if($carttotal >= 16 && $carttotal <= 20){
                    $cost = 20000;
                }else if($carttotal >= 11 && $carttotal <= 15){
                    $cost = 15000;
                }else if($carttotal >= 6 && $carttotal <= 10){
                    $cost = 10000;
                }else if($carttotal <= 5 && $carttotal >= 1){
                    $cost = 5000;
                }

                $rate = array(
                    'id' => $this->id,
                    'label' => 'Shipping',
                    'cost' => $cost,
                );

                // Register the rate
                $this->add_rate( $rate );

            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'your_shipping_method_init' );

function add_your_shipping_method( $methods ) {
    $methods['your_shipping_method'] = 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method';
    return $methods;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_your_shipping_method' );
```

Cheers.